# Need to create a function that saves a google apps script (or fixes the original function)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm just beginning my JS journey. Currently trying to update a MailChimp API call within Google Sheets Script. The issue is that the script (originally found here:https://medium.hackinrio.com/mailchimp-reports-in-google-sheets-88496a153ee2 [1](https://medium.hackinrio.com/mailchimp-reports-in-google-sheets-88496a153ee2)) only works when you SAVE the Google Scripts editor. I would like to create a JavaScript GAS function that is able to run every day that saves the Script Editor thereby updating the MailChimp count. Or some other solution that would allow this to work.

Google Scripts Function:

```
function getSubscribersCount(api_key, list_id) {
  var API_KEY = api_key;
  var LIST_ID = list_id;

  var dc = '(my mailchimp API Key goes here)'.split('-')[1];
  var api = 'https://'+ dc +'.api.mailchimp.com/2.0';
  var membersPath = '/lists/members.json';

  // MC api-specific parameters
  var payload = {
    "apikey": API_KEY,
    "id": LIST_ID
  }; 

  // GAS specific parameters: 
  var params = {
    "method": "POST",
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
    "payload": payload
  };

  var apiCall = function(endpoint){
    var apiResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(api+endpoint, params);
    var json = JSON.parse(apiResponse);
    return json;
  };
var members = apiCall(membersPath);
  return members.total;
}
```

Is there a function I can add that will enable me to save the function, or perhaps emulate a CMD + s keyboard event?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing a formula into your spreadsheet to invoking your script you should write another function that modifies the spreadsheet directly.

```
function updateSubscriberCount() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"),
      api_key = sheet.getRange("B1").getValue(),
      list_id = sheet.getRange("C1").getValue();
  sheet.getRange("A1").setValue(getSubscribersCount(api_key, list_id));
}
```

Then you click on "edit/current project's triggers" and set up a timer to run that function at regular intervals.
However you have to run that function manually at least once to grant the script the permissions it needs.